# Extracting a table Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi guys I want to extract data from a table but the <td doesn't have class, is only the <td. How would I extract them specifically?

I want to extract lines 3 and 5. How would I do that?
[Place I want to extract data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx4MS.png)
And this is my code.[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huCgH.png)
My code's line 30 was where I was going to extract line 3 and in line 31 I'm planning to extract line 5.
I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternetaviley,

```
bloques.select("td")[0].text #This will give the text of first value
bloques.select("td")[2].text #This will give the text of third value
```

Answer (score 0):

to get line 3

```
columna.find_all('td')[0]
```